# Could not parse base64 DER-encoded ASN.1 public key from iOS in Golang

Tags: ios, go, swift3, rsa, public-key-encryption

i have a projects in Golang with RSA enryption, so now, i have a Base64 public key format which used for encrypt a message,

i used this code:

```
publicKeyBase64 = "MIGJAoGBAJJYXgBem1scLKPEjwKrW8+ci3B/YNN3aY2DJ3lc5e2wNc0SmFikDpow1TdYcKl2wdrXX7sMRsyjTk15IECMezyHzaJGQ9TinnkQixJ+YnlNdLC04TNWOg13plyahIXBforYAjYl2wVIA8Yma2bEQFhmAFkEX1A/Q1dIKy6EfQ+xAgMBAAE="
publicKeyBinary, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(publicKeyBase64)

publicKeyInterface, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(publicKeyBinary)
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Could not parse DER encoded public key (encryption key)")
    return "","",err
}

publicKey, isRSAPublicKey := publicKeyInterface.(*rsa.PublicKey)
if !isRSAPublicKey {
    fmt.Println("Public key parsed is not an RSA public key")
    return "","",err
}

encryptedMessage, err := rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, publicKey, "message")
```

When i run this code, i got this error:

```
Could not parse DER encoded public key (encryption key)

asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:0 tag:2 length:129 isCompound:false}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} AlgorithmIdentifier @3
```

The error points to publicKeyInterface, it failed to parse from Base64 decoded format to public Key, What's the problem with my code ?

=======updated=====

my publicKeyBase64 is retrieved from my models with Binary Data type

When i store it in my mongoDB from my Rails API, i receive public_key params as Base64 format, but i decode it to binary and then i stored it with this code

```
def create
  params = device_params      
  public_key = Base64.decode64 device_params[:public_key]
  #device_params[:public_key] value is "MIGJAoGBAJJYXgBem1scLKPEjwKrW8+ci3B/YNN3aY2DJ3lc5e2wNc0SmFikDpow1TdYcKl2wdrXX7sMRsyjTk15IECMezyHzaJGQ9TinnkQixJ+YnlNdLC04TNWOg13plyahIXBforYAjYl2wVIA8Yma2bEQFhmAFkEX1A/Q1dIKy6EfQ+xAgMBAAE="
  params[:public_key] = BSON::Binary.new(public_key, :generic)
  device = Device.find_or_create_by(id: device_params[:id])

  render_success device.update_attributes(params), device
end
```

When i use rails code to convert my Base64 public key string using this code, it succeeded:

```
rsa_public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(Base64.decode64(public_key))
```

in my iOS app, i use https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/AsymmetricCrypto 
to generate a public Key using this code:

```
AsymmetricCryptoManager.sharedInstance.createSecureKeyPair({ (success, error) -> Void in
   if success {
    print("RSA-1024 keypair successfully generated.")
    let publicKey = AsymmetricCryptoManager.sharedInstance.getPublicKeyData()?.base64EncodedString()

    let url = ENV.BASE_URL + "devices"
    let headers = ["Authentication-Token": CurrentUser.getCurrentUser().token] as! HTTPHeaders
    let params = ["device[user_id]": CurrentUser.getCurrentUser().id!, "device[id]": instanceID,"device[token]": fcmToken, "device[os]": "ios", "device[public_key]": publicKey!]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
} else { print("An error happened while generating a keypair: \(error)") }
})
```

Comment: Can you show the code that generates the base64 key?

Comment: I retrieve it from my models with Binary Data data type actually
`publicKeyBase64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(publicKey.Data)`

Comment: What is `Data`? That's not a field of a `rsa.PublicKey`.

Comment: it's from my struct  `PublicKey  bson.Binary`

Comment: Ok, that still doesn't help. Where does it originally come from? Is it the `block.Bytes` from a pem block? If not, you're probably storing the wrong thing, or trying to decode it the wrong way. RIght now, we just know it's base64.

Comment: oh, no, i don't use pem string, it originally comes from my device (iOS), i encoded public Key generated from my device with Base64 and save it in my mongoDB as a Binary Data, and as you can see the Base64 value is exactly the same as `publicKeyBase64`, i test it in my Rails Console to convert it to rsa_public_key and it succeeded

Comment: Then please show the code you use in Rails. We still don't know what this data actually represents. It may not be base64-encoded ASN.1 data.

Comment: The ruby code you added just writes the key. You said you managed to construct a working public key from the data. Please show that code.

Comment: you mean my code in iOS app?

Comment: So far, you have not shown that the base64 data is actually a public key. You need to show the code that uses it as such, not just encoding and storing. Until then, we can assume it's just random data.

Comment: ok, i have added my code for generate a public key in iOS app

Comment: Not sure why ruby is happy, but your ASN.1 is barebones. You need to first convert it to PEM for anyone outside iOS to be able to read it properly: https://digitalleaves.com/blog/2015/10/sharing-public-keys-between-ios-and-the-rest-of-the-world/. Or to the ASN.1 parsing yourself and extract the values yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can dump the ASN.1 contents to see what they look like:

```
$ echo "MIGJAoGBAJJYXgBem1scLKPEjwKrW8+ci3B/YNN3aY2DJ3lc5e2wNc0SmFikDpow1TdYcKl2wdrXX7sMRsyjTk15IECMezyHzaJGQ9TinnkQixJ+YnlNdLC04TNWOg13plyahIXBforYAjYl2wVIA8Yma2bEQFhmAFkEX1A/Q1dIKy6EfQ+xAgMBAAE=" | \
    base64 -d | \
    dumpasn1 -
  0 137: SEQUENCE {
  3 129:   INTEGER
       :     00 92 58 5E 00 5E 9B 5B 1C 2C A3 C4 8F 02 AB 5B
       :     CF 9C 8B 70 7F 60 D3 77 69 8D 83 27 79 5C E5 ED
       :     B0 35 CD 12 98 58 A4 0E 9A 30 D5 37 58 70 A9 76
       :     C1 DA D7 5F BB 0C 46 CC A3 4E 4D 79 20 40 8C 7B
       :     3C 87 CD A2 46 43 D4 E2 9E 79 10 8B 12 7E 62 79
       :     4D 74 B0 B4 E1 33 56 3A 0D 77 A6 5C 9A 84 85 C1
       :     7E 8A D8 02 36 25 DB 05 48 03 C6 26 6B 66 C4 40
       :     58 66 00 59 04 5F 50 3F 43 57 48 2B 2E 84 7D 0F
       :     B1
135   3:   INTEGER 65537
       :   }

0 warnings, 0 errors.
```

A well-formatted ASN.1 public key should include the algorithm as well. We should have a line similar to:

```
  5   9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)
```

The `AsymmetricCryptoManager.getPublicKeyData()` returns a very barebones  `ASN.1` key, without any algorithm information. This makes Go very unhappy as it has no way of knowing what kind of key it is. See [more about correctly exporting the key here](https://digitalleaves.com/blog/2015/10/sharing-public-keys-between-ios-and-the-rest-of-the-world/).

**If you can change the iOS code**, you should instead use [CryptoExportImportManager](https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/CryptoExportImportManager) and use one of `exportPublicKeyToPEM` or `exportPublicKeyToDER`. These take the output of `getPublicKeyData` and generate output usable by other tools. You can find an example of how to use them in the [CryptoExportImportManager example](https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/CryptoExportImportManager/blob/master/CryptoLoadExternalCertificate/ExportViewController.swift#L44).

**If you cannot change the key export code**, you can instead parse it directly in Go. This assumes that you know for sure that it is a RSA public key:

```
func main() {
    publicKeyBase64 := "MIGJAoGBAJJYXgBem1scLKPEjwKrW8+ci3B/YNN3aY2DJ3lc5e2wNc0SmFikDpow1TdYcKl2wdrXX7sMRsyjTk15IECMezyHzaJGQ9TinnkQixJ+YnlNdLC04TNWOg13plyahIXBforYAjYl2wVIA8Yma2bEQFhmAFkEX1A/Q1dIKy6EfQ+xAgMBAAE="

    // Base64 decode.
    publicKeyBinary, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(publicKeyBase64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // rsa.PublicKey is a big.Int (N: modulus) and an integer (E: exponent).
    var pubKey rsa.PublicKey
    if rest, err := asn1.Unmarshal(publicKeyBinary, &pubKey); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else if len(rest) != 0 {
        panic("rest is not nil")
    }

    fmt.Printf("key: %+v\n", pubKey)
}
```

This prints out:

> key:
>   {N:+102767083290202280873554060983826675083148443795791447833515664566475334389364583758312108980110921996262487865832851258326049062353432991986398760705560379825908169063986770245967781444794847106351934016144540466696422397564949226710181429429140226472206572796987719088983654589217713611861345869296293449649
>   E:65537}

You can now use your public key in package rsa functions.

Comment: I use another Base64 encoded from my friend (comes from android, but don't know yet what library he's using right now) and it works fine with current code
`"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDkx9h4KXOoW+2Kb06pLz7vo3GN3iGqWk8sS2SxvRSM+/S6bmhrt2Mw+StSSzQSn4YMhF1rEU7fED1buI85bx8QpFwdAu1MzB1uWVXSo/koM3voAzghQTiCvoJigxgIHtKdr2e03D9vWYQPxh862yFIstzItCgksliSwLXD5++IKQIDAQAB"`

Comment: I think it is better to change my iOS code to send valid public Key with Base64 encoded format

Comment: Your friend's key includes the algorithm: `echo ... | base64 -d | dumpasn1 -` shows `.... OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption ...`. Yours did not, just integers.

Comment: And I agree, if you can change the iOS code, that will be much more durable. Other libraries/tools will have the same problem as Go. It's also good if you want to allow EC keys.

Comment: i think, i prefer to fix the `AsymmetricCryptoManager.getPublicKeyData()` in `AsymmetricCryptoManager.swift`  to add the algorithm information, but i'm still confused how to add it. I have change the default of `kAsymmetricCryptoManagerKeySize` value to 1024 from 2048 (because i just need 1024)

Comment: You should be able to just call `CryptoExportImportManager().exportPublicKeyToDER(AsymmetricCryptoManager.sharedInstance.getPublicKeyData(), kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, 1024)`. The size needs to match the key, but 1024 or 2048 is up to you.

Comment: ohh, so i need to have both AsymmetricCryptoManager library for generate public key and CryptoExportImportManager to export the public key to my backend

Comment: That's correct, you still get the key the same way, `CryptoExportImportManager` just converts it to something more standard. I've added a link to the example from that library, it shows you how to use both.

Comment: alright, how about the private key? should i add the algorithm information in private key at AsymmetricCryptoManager.swift ? Because when i try to decode my encrypted message from my public key, it got failed, it almost finish and after i can decrypt my message, it is done

Comment: If you're only decrypting, you shouldn't need to send the private key. Not sure how to export this one if you do though. Also, make sure you decrypt with the same parameters, mainly the padding. `SecPadding.PKCS1` in this case.

Comment: hmm, i don't need to export the private key, i just need to decrypt it in my iOS app (encrypted_message sent from Go). Right now it is failed to decrypt, and i suspicious i should modify something for decrypting it

Comment: This is technically a separate question. But the main thing is the padding.

Comment: for encryption in Go, i use `rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, publicKey, message)`  and in iOS i use just `PKCS1`, is it different?

Comment: I have made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780248/can-i-decrypt-my-encrypted-message-from-my-go-using-encryptpkcs1v15-in-ios

Comment: Not sure, `PKCS1` refers to the whole family, though I would assume it would use 1.5. Still, for plaintext encryption, it's recommended to use [EncryptOAEP](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#EncryptOAEP). Even then, encrypting messages with RSA is iffy, you should be generating a session key and encrypting that, then using the session key to encrypt your plaintext. RSA is meant more for session establishment than actual data encryption.

Comment: when i try to encrypt from rails, it works fine when i try to decode encryption_message in iOS with PKCS1 padding, so the problem occurs when Go encrypt it with PKCS1v15

Comment: Fair enough, it could be different versions of PKCS#1, they don't specify what they're using. Still, the point stands: you probably want OAEP.